# Does the MongoDB .Net driver version 1.8.2 support $geoWithin Geospatial Query Selector

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I’m using MongoDB 2.4 and I’m  looking for Geospatial Query Selectors support in the MongoDB .Net driver version 1.8.2.

I see support for  $geoIntersects (MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.GeoIntersects), $near (MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.Near), $nearSphere (MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query.Near).

Does the MongoDB .Net driver version 1.8.2 support $geoWithin??????

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB C# driver still uses the (deprecated) `$within` as opposed to `$geoWithin`. [Here is the relevant open JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-774) if you'd like to keep an eye on it. :)